# SQLite3 connection from StringIO (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, stringio

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to generate a connection to a SQLite database in python from a StringIO object.

I have a compressed SQLite3 database file and I would like to decompress it using the `gzip` library and then connect to it without first making a temp file.

I've looked into the `slqite3` library source, but it looks like `filename` gets passed all the way through into the C code. Are there any other SQLite3 connection libraries that you could use a file ID for? Or is there some why I can trick the builtin `sqlite3` library into thinking that my StringIO (or some other object type) is an actual file?

Comment: Uncompress it to a RAM disk perhaps?

Comment: What's the use case for this? Load some existing data already in sqlite3 format, do some work with it, and discard any changes after?

Comment: I only need to get a few columns from a compressed database object. I will be working with it in python objects after that.

Comment: Short of a tempfile then, what about pickling the sqlite3 data, and then loading that to work with? If it's gzipped, then presumably it's not from a constantly changing data source, so a once off pickling could be feasible... (and could be reasonably small enough to not require compressing)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't write and compress the sqlite file, I'm getting it as is from another application.

Comment: Umm... so something else is using sqlite3, then gzipping it and you get that? Umm...

Comment: Might be a very hackish way around it - what OS is it running on?

Comment: I'm not Windows 7 right now, but it's a reasonable assumption that it could be used on another version of Windows. I can't imagine it will need to work on OSX or Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python sqlite3 module cannot open a database from a file number, and even so, using StringIO will not give you a file number (since it does not open a file, it just emulates the Python `file` object).

You can use the `:memory:` special file name to avoid writing a file to disk, then later write it to disk once you are done with it. This will also make sure the file is optimized for size, and you can opt not to write e.g. indexes if size is really a big issue.

Comment: Yep, but when I use `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` it initializes an empty database.

Comment: How do you later write it to disk?

Comment: The `sqlitebck` module does this, but it sounds like the OP was more looking for a way to extract data from a few tables, in which case basic select+insert is probably easier.